# knitr ezspin there is no package called ‘R.oo’

Tags: r, knitr

I cannot get `ezspin` to work; I keep getting the error message `there is no package called ‘R.oo’`. In my current working directory I have a folder called `misc` which contains a file called `test.csv`which has the following code:

```
#' ---
#' title: "testing"
#' date: "April 6, 2016"
#' output: 
#'    word_document:
#'       reference_docx: template5.docx
#' ---

#+ eval=TRUE
a <- function(){
   a <- read.csv("misc/test.csv")
   print (a)
}
a()
```

Obviously this has a hard-coded path to the `misc` directory.  If I have this script open in RStudio, then I can click on the Compile Notebook button to create the MS Word document just fine.

I have a subdirectory called `WD`. In a script called `ezspintest.R` I have tried to run this without success:

```
library(ezknitr)
ezspin("misc/test.R", wd = "WD")
```

The entire error message is `Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :   there is no package called ‘R.oo’`

Need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, try installing the R.oo package:

http://cran.mirrors.hoobly.com/web/packages/R.oo/index.html

Comment: well, duh.  That was easy.  Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing. The package name is a bit cryptic, but I recognized it from a past project.